# Mysql - Joining on multiple IDs and concating joined column?

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

Not sure how accurate my question title is but let me explain a little better.

I have two tables: artists, releases

```
table artist
  artist_id, 
  artist_name

table release
  release_id,
  release_artist_ids,
  release_name
```

There are more column names, but these are the ones involved in my problem.

release_artist_ids can contain one or more artist IDs that correspond to the artist table. If more than one artist features on the same release_id then I had comma separated the IDs.

So an example release row:

> 1 -- 2,5 -- Example Release

What I would like to do is list the releases and join the artist table to fetch the artist names involved in the release.

I managed to join using IN (release.release_artist_ids) but this only brings back one artist name. I would like to merge all involved artists into one returned column, separated by a pipe so I can format later on.

Comment: You should really get rid of the comma separated IDs and properly normalize your tables. See this question for ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7457643/723693

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you change your database design to have a [join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) called `release_artist` that models the many-to-many relationship between artists and releases. This table should have two columns: `release_id` and `artist_id`.

If you can't change the database design, you can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) but it will be slow:

```
SELECT
   release.release_id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(artist.artist_name, '|') AS artist_names
FROM artist 
JOIN release
ON FIND_IN_SET(artist.id, release.release_artist_ids)
GROUP BY release.release_id
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I had not thought of making an additional table for the release artists.